# Basic Auth not working on cross domain call Angular

Tags: angularjs, basic-authentication

I set the request header for Basic Auth inside app.run

```
 app.run(['$route', '$http', 'Base64', function ($route, $http, Base64) {

        var encoded = Base64.encode(userName + ':' + password);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded;

    }]);
```

Inside data context when I tried to make a call with the blow mentioned code to the external api, I am getting 401 unauthorized user error. Any suggestion?

```
  var deffered = $q.defer();
  var resource= $resource('url',{});
            resource.query({ isArray: true }, function (data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }, function (status) {
                deffered.reject(status);
            });
            return deffered.promise;
```

Comment: What does the request look like in the Network panel of DevTools ? Is the Autorization header set ?

Comment: Yes it is, please check out the screenshots.https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ovcgjpfxejwkfq/headers.PNG, https://www.dropbox.com/s/tb8vw82s43ffa26/screen.PNG

Comment: Seems like a server-side issue. There seems to be an OPTIONS request (sent automatically by Chrome since this is a CORS request), which get rejected by the server. Are you sure you have properly configured the server to allow OPTIONS requests ? What language does your backend speak ?